# Dedicated server issues with SSL and IPs, content showing on wrong site

Tags: web-hosting, https

We have a number of sites on this dedicated server. Pages from one site are showing up on another site. Example:

- clientsite1.com (right site, no SSL installed)
- clientsite2.com (forwards to SSL, shows right site)
- clientsite1.com (no SSL installed, WRONG site, shows clientsite2 after "untrusted connection" message)

Now I'm in WHM and this is what I see: [image: http://i.imgur.com/GOBRuWa.jpg]

The one that says "Is primary website on IP address?" is the one that's showing up improperly across all non-SSL domains. I am assuming this is because the OTHER domain on our IP address has "Web SNI" enabled, which apparently allows you to use multiple certificates on one IP?

To fix this problem, would someone confirm these steps please?

1. Get each site on own dedicated IP.
2. Delete the SSL host for each site in WHM.
3. Re-add the SSL host for each site in WHM, with new dedicated IP address.

Or I can somehow also enable "Web SNI" for the domain that is currently showing improperly? Not sure how to do that, but I'll look it up if someone can confirm it will fix the problem.

I found [another question](https://serverfault.com/questions/309672/problem-with-ssl-and-hosting-provider#comment297937_309694) on here with this comment but I'm not sure if it applies to my situation: *"... at least on Apache a properly setup name-based virtualhost should display the correct content, even with SSL (I've used this myself). You'll get the "this is a bogus cert" warning, but if the client accepts the cert, the client will still send the Host header to the server, which Apache should use to select a VirtualHost block and show the correct content, not someone else's site."* Is that the case here? If this is the case, what can I say to my webhost that will make them understand (and fix!) the problem?

Comment: Can you post what your VirtualHosts setup looks like? It sounds like Apache is currently configured to default all HTTPS traffic to your clientsite2.com content, and you get the SSL warning because the hostname you're requesting (clientsite1.com) doesn't match the SSL certificate presented by your server (clientsite2.com). Basically you need to make sure you have a VirtualHost setup for clientsite1.com that listens on port 80 AND 443. Then you'll get the right content, but still the SSL warning until you install a certificate for it.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. But I'm sorry nathangiesbrecht, I'm not sure how to access vhosts for simple viewing in WHM. I found how to prepend/append to the vhosts file, but not how to actually view the vhosts file and set-up I already have. Do you think it's worth a shot to just try and set up a virtual host in the file that gets included after vhosts for one of my sites? I believe I can manage that -- I use XAMPP to develop locally so I'm familiar with creating vhosts. Thanks again!

Comment: I think the vhosts process in WHM is managed automatically. It may be that a vhost on port 443 is only activated when you install an SSL for a sub-account, I'm not sure. You'll also need to have a separate IP address for each domain that you want on HTTPS.

Comment: Yep! Got it all sorted with another IP address (after needing to bug the host to fix it). Thanks! Not sure what the procedure is but I'd be happy to accept your answer if you post it as one @nathangiesbrecht!