# How do I use CPanel to prevent the HTTPS URL for my site from showing somebody else's site?

Tags: https, cpanel

Currently if you go to the https of my site it just goes to another persons site on the server nothing to do with me.

Anyway, how can I just turn it off port 443 using cPanel so it just either 404's or redirects to my http version instead

Comment: Are you on a shared server?

Comment: Yes I am on a shared server and the same website is appearing even for the servers main cPanel https as well. So I am guessing the server host has misconfigured the server. This seems to happen everytime I get shared hosting and would really like to know a quick and easy way to prevent this from occuring everytime.

Comment: It could be a limitation of SSL on a shared server where the first site created on the server is shown. Have you talked to your host??

Comment: Presumably you get a browser warning that you must click through before getting "to another persons site"? (Since the domain on the SSL cert is different to your domain?)

Comment: Here is a question about how to set up the hosting side properly: [Dedicated server issues with SSL and IPs, content showing on wrong site](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/78794/dedicated-server-issues-with-ssl-and-ips-content-showing-on-wrong-site)

Answer (score 2):

It does not appear that CPanal has functionality for disabling SSL for your domain for shared hosting situations. Rather, you should use the CPanel functionality for setting up SSL.

If you don't want to pay for a SSL certificate, you can generate and self-sign one yourself.   Browsers won't allow users to access your SSL site without bypassing some scary looking warning dialog boxes, but at least it won't show somebody else's site.   The full instructions for doing so are here: https://confluence2.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Generate+an+SSL+Certificate+and+Signing+Request

If you can pay for a certificate, the instructions for installing the certificate that you purchased are here: https://confluence2.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Purchase+and+Install+an+SSL+Certificate

Comment: If you didn't want to pay for a certificate but want a trusted one, you could possibly also look at http://letsencrypt.org

Comment: I also use [StartSSL](https://www.startssl.com/) which has a free single domain option.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** As has been pointed out in the comments, what I've explained here isn't entirely true these days (perhaps I'm a bit old fashioned). It *may* still hold true if your host has not configured their servers for [SNI](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication), though.

---

Shared servers share IP addresses between multiple sites, and use the domain name in the request headers from the user's browser to determine which site to return.

SSL however requires one IP per site because the server doesn't know at first which domain is being requested (due to the request headers being encrypted). Thus it has to determine which site to return based on the IP address.

Multiple IP addresses can easily be bound to the same shared server, and this is how shared hosting supports SSL.

Most shared hosts use one IP on a server for all the non-secure sites, and then have a certain number of IPs they'll assign to each server for the purposes of SSL sites.

It sounds like in this case, the host has just given the main shared IP to one of the secure sites (either that or they've mistakenly set you up on the same IP they already assigned individually to that secure site).

This has the result you're seeing because that solitary secure site is bound to that IP address for HTTPS requests - irrespective of the domain name requested, because that can't be determined.

You can't do anything yourself to fix this. But what you should do is ask your host to assign their IP addresses properly, or if they won't, move hosts.

Comment: [It is no longer the case that HTTPS requires a dedicated IP address](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13988/is-unique-ip-address-a-must-for-ssl).  Server Name Indication (SNI) allows many HTTPS hosts to share an IP address.  [Apache supports SNI](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI) as long as it is compiled correctly.  This allows HTTPS to be configured as virtual hosts.  CPanel has functionality built in for setting up SSL even in shared hosting situations.

Comment: Oh, thanks @StephenOstermiller! I don't think I've been on a shared host that uses SNI (at least, I haven't noticed if it has been the case). I've added a note to my answer.

Comment: Not all hosts have the correct versions of Apache and CPanel configured to allow this.   There are certainly hosts out there which won't allow SSL without buying a dedicated IP address.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a hint rather than an answer (since I don't have reputation points).

Something similar happened to me when I was playing around with nginx file, configuring SSL on a private server. If you are seeing a security error message in Google Chrome before redirection then its quite possible that the server was not configured properly. Being on a shared hosting, there's nothing much you can do since you don't have access to nginx/apache file.

And do note that, as mentioned in comments, shared hosting doesn't have such limitation. I have seen shared hosts providing SSL support without any problem.

Additionally, and this is just a recommendation, switch host! You don't want to be stuck in a security nightmare because of ill configured settings :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Apache server, which is likely if you are using CPanel, you can install a .htaccess file that either prohibits HTTPS access or uses URL rewriting to redirect HTTPS URLs to HTTP.